# java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "" error

Tags: java, android

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ayak1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);      
    say1 = Integer.parseInt(ayak1.getText().toString());
    button1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);        
    button1.setOnClickListener(this);


}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v==button1){
        int sonuc=(say1)*(6)/(10);
        String total = String.valueOf(sonuc);
        fiyat.setText(total);
    }
```

this is the code,can you please help?

Comment: move this `say1 = Integer.parseInt(ayak1.getText().toString());` to `onClick`. To check if its empty use `if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(say1))` do something

Answer (score 3):

Your `ayak1.getText().toString()` String is empty. `Integer.parseInt()` would give you `NumberFormatException` if you pass to it an empty String (or any String that can't be parsed as an int).